# Visual studio rc 2017-unable to create project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS2017 and xamarin, but when I'm going to create a cross platform poject this message comes up: `The file Content.json could not be found within the project templates. Continuing to run, but the resulting project may not build properly.` . And when I build the resulting: lot of bugs-errors.
Help needed, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Adding a shared(PCL) project and after that a Android Blank App(Project), solved the problem with the latest vs17 RC version, while creating a cross-platform project.